# Could not load 'active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter'. Windows 7 local server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

I have been going through the Rails tutorial, https://www.railstutorial.org/book/static_pages, and the first two chapters went fine. I installed Rails on my Laptop made a hello world app and a toy with the scaffold generator. There were some things I had to do differently because I am doing everything locally instead of on a cloud environment and because I am using Windows 7, but I got everything to work.

When I tried running a local server and going to my http://localhost:3000/static_pages/home page, i got the error in the Title. The following is the full error message:

Could not load 'active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter'. Make sure that the adapter in config/database.yml is valid. If you use an adapter other than 'mysql', 'mysql2', 'postgresql' or 'sqlite3' add the necessary adapter gem to the Gemfile.

I figure it must be something with the Gemfile because that was the only difference between this and my other apps, I'm just not sure what to change. I included the Gemfile and the database.yml. Thanks in advance.

```
#Gemfile - sample_app
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails',                   '4.2.2'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', :require => 'bcrypt'
gem 'faker',                   '1.4.2'
gem 'carrierwave',             '0.10.0'
gem 'mini_magick',             '3.8.0'
gem 'fog',                     '1.23.0'
gem 'will_paginate',           '3.0.7'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.10'
gem 'bootstrap-sass',          '3.2.0.0'
gem 'sass-rails',              '5.0.2'
gem 'uglifier',                '2.5.3'
gem 'coffee-rails',            '4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails',            '4.0.3'
gem 'turbolinks',              '2.3.0'
gem 'jbuilder',                '2.2.3'
gem 'sdoc',                    '0.4.0', group: :doc

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'sqlite3'
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

group :test do
  gem 'minitest-reporters', '1.0.5'
  gem 'mini_backtrace',     '0.1.3'
  gem 'guard-minitest',     '2.3.1'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
  gem 'puma',           '2.11.1'
end
```

Database.yml

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

Comment: Which version of Ruby are you running?

Comment: From ruby -v in the command prompt it says ruby 2.1.5p273

Comment: Can you give us some output when you run `bundle install`?

Comment: Have you successfully used SQLite with a previous ruby program or example in the tutorial?  IOW, how have you tested that SQLite is working and that you can access those databases? ([path-to-your-example-app]/db/development.sqlite3, [path-to-your-example-app]/db/test.sqlite3, and [path-to-your-example-app]/db/production.sqlite3

Comment: The previous examples in the tutorial were working. So I uninstalled rails and reinstalled. Then I used the gemfile from the other examples and that seemed to work. I don't understand the problem but that worked. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

In your Gemfile, you specify sqlite3 (the 'sqlite3' gem) for development and testing, and postgres (the 'pg' gem) for production.
But in your database.yml, you've specified the production database as sqlite3:

```
<database.yml>
 ...
production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

which will try to use the default adapter (`sqlite3`) and will look for a database file with `.sqlite3` as the file extension.

You need to change your `database.yml` so that it uses a **postgres** database:

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
  database: db/production
```

(Make sure you have postgres running on your machine either as an app or as a service.)

Or you can change your Gemfile so that you use SQLite3 for production, too.

If you tried to run the production version on your Windows machine but perhaps were running a development or test version on your OSX machine, this could be the problem.